# Calculated Date [Sharepoint Online]

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, date-time, calculated-column-formula, date

Currently having an issue with a calculated date column when the field is not filled in. Displays the date as December 1899.

Current formula is:

```
=TEXT(YEAR([Closed Date]),"00")&"-"&TEXT(MONTH([Closed Date]),"00")&" "&TEXT([Closed Date],"mmm")
```

Unsure of how best to wrap ISBLANK around it.

```
=ISBLANK (IF TEXT(YEAR([Closed Date]),"00")&"-"&TEXT(MONTH([Closed Date]),"00")&" "&TEXT([Closed Date],"mmm"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an IF statement outside of the ISBLANK

```
IF(ISBLANK([Closed Date]),"no date available", yourlongTEXTformattinghere)
```

Comment: Absolutely spot on, works perfectly.